# In Ionic ng-class not working in directive ion-nav-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework, ng-class

In ionic if I added an ng-class to ion-nav-view and it doesn't have any effect.

HTML:

```
<ion-nav-view ng-class="{'test': $root.test}"></ion-nav-view>
```

JS:

```
.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.test = true;
    ...
```

But `test` class is not added
[image]

Is it because the ionic directive doesn't support an ng-class?
Directive code is at https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/1.x/js/angular/directive/navView.js

I just add a console log of the arguments and ng-class attributte is there:
[image]

Comment: Have you try using just test instead of 'test'?

Comment: @MECM nothing changes

Comment: http://corpus.hubwiz.com/2/ionic-framework/29055605.html
Maybe this can help you

Comment: Thanks but didn't work